# I Need Help With Testfor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Okay, so I'm making a sell shop in Minecraft using commands, but I need to know, how do I get different types of logs using the command?

/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:log",Count:32b}]}

I've tried doing log:2 and all that, and I can't find anything online. Could someone please help?

Comment: What do you mean by "get different types of logs using the command"? Do you want to detect any type of log, or a specific type of log (if so, which?).

Comment: @colorfusion I want to use a different type of log, like birch or spruce.

Comment: If you want the command to allow a specific type of log only, and not other types, then Skylinerw's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Damage` short tag stores the Damage value of the item:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:log",Damage:2s,Count:32b}]}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that Acacia and Dark Oak have the id of `minecraft:log2`.

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
/tesfor @p[Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:log",Damage:3,Count:32}]]
```

Comment: That's not how target selectors work. You cannot insert NBT data directly into a selector. Even futher, when testing for pre-existing data, you must include datatypes for all tags.